# overflow (scroll) to work with negative `left` and `top` positioned elements

Tags: html, css

What is the workaround to allow scrollable `overflow` with elements positioned negatively from left and top?

Like [here in example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/pb4bh/), only 3 of the red squares are visible and scroll is not toggled. Although there are 6 of the squares, 3 of them positioned negative of top.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using negative positions, then wanting them to flow like regular elements within those negative margins?

Comment: I do not want them to flow like regular elements, it's just this particular example. See http://jsfiddle.net/m85Na/ (a different generated result from my app.).

Comment: Is this the [kind of effect](http://jsfiddle.net/pb4bh/3/) that you're thinking of? Nevermind the extra boxes, I'm wondering about the scroll behavior.

Comment: Whoops, had a leftover definition I forgot to remove. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/pb4bh/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to wrap the squares in a div the same height as them and use JQuery's scrollTop() method: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp but this will also force a horizontal scrollbar beneath the wrapper div... short answer: no CSS-only solution, and positioning them absolutely obviates the scroll for this solution - try floating left and clearing each row if you want to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only solution I could find is setting `min-height` & `min-width` using JavaScript (I wasn't using jQuery at all on this project).

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap it another div and give it overflow property.

http://jsfiddle.net/pb4bh/1/

Comment: This only seems to work because there's padded added to the wrapper div in the amount that the children are overflowing. I don't think it would work if the application was dynamic, at least not without a some JS logic to change the padding as things are moved